# Handling users that exist, but try to login through Facebook OAuth / etc

Tags: facebook, oauth, twitter-oauth

I've got a decent set of existing users on my website who login via their emailaddress as their username.

I'm setting up Facebook OAuth mechanism to allow new users to sign up more conveniently, but I'm not sure how to handle the scenario when a user who already has an email address registered with our system and now tries to login via Facebook.

1. Should I consider him the same user?
2. Should I treat him like a new user?

The situation is more complicated by the fact that I dont validate their email addresses (when  they login directly into my system), so i cant assume they are the same user.

How do others resolve this conflict, or do other folks simply treat this user connecting via FB as a new entity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your login screen, users can have a choice: you may put

- new user: signup using facebook

since this is a totally new user account, then you just need to do your facebook connect + request for email permission, etc.

- existing user: login by email

Once they do this, let them login using the old-fashioned way. Then once signed in, prompt them to connect this email address to their facebook account. So the flow is login via email then optional facebook connect.

To do this, I assume you've added a field on your database table for user_accounts, that is **facebook_user_id** or **fb_id** or **user_id**, etc. Then on facebook connect, get the logged-in-email, `UPDATE table SET fb_id = xxx WHERE email = xx`

Comment: @dragonjet - part of the problem is that if a 'plain' user signed up as 'a@b.com' directly on my site, I do NOT verify whether that email belongs to him actually. So, if another user (or the same guy, I dont know) tries signing up via FB and has a@b.com registered to him - which has been verified by FB, what should I do? How do I resolve the clash?

Comment: This goes back to the issue, on your original email registration, did you have email verification where you will send registrants an email and they will click on a confirmation link?

If you did, then you will be sure that the email is his and the facebook account is also his because he was able to login. Linking this currently logged in facebook account and currently logged in email is safe.

If another user signed up with an existing email, that won't be a problem. Still record the FB user_id and let them re-enter a new email.

Comment: @drajonjet - so, actually, no - we dont confirm the email address in a "direct" registration. So, we have a conflict problem, as well as the (smaller) issue if a FB user has signed up with an email address, do we reject others trying to register the same email address?

Comment: any thoughts on how other sites do this? a working example of "once they do this, let them login using the old-fashioned way. then once signed in, promt them to connect this email address to their facebook account. So the flow is login via email then optional facebook connect."

Comment: Ok then another solution is: all signup / login is through facebook connect. Once he is logged in, that is the time you will ask "connect this account with an old email account". If the user does not do this, then that's the time you get email from his facebook info or let him enter new email.

Comment: ended up separating the accounts completely

Comment: This is a link to facebook's suggestion https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/multiple-providers/

Answer (score 0):

I've pondered the same issue. I think we'll go with the verified email (Facebook Connect) getting attached to and logged into the existing account with the same email.

Before we connect and log them in we'll explain that the account exist and ask for their password (they signed up using email and password, so they should know it) to ensure it's the right person.

If you support multiple external authentications (Google OAuth, Facebook etc) then you may not have a password, and in that case it gets slightly trickier.

*If you do log them in to the existing account without asking for a password, make sure you clear existing sessions to avoid 'anticipation attacks', where an attacker anticipates that the target signs up, creates an account and keep the session after they've signed up and attached to the attackers existing account.*